# create table and set names to it

Tags: r

I want to create a table and set the names to it but it does not work as expected. Actually, I can't find what is wrong

```
arr <- array(dim = c(1,5))
names(arr) <- c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Name", "Surname")
```

Comment: Check the class of "arr".. Its a matrix.For a matrix, define column names using either colnames function instead of names.

Comment: You may want to ask this question differently. I'm not sure you want a matrix. What's the purpose of your data structure?  Depending on the purpose, something like this might work better: `var <- c(Year = 2305, Month = "July", Day = 13, Name = "Jean-Luc", Surname = "Picard")`

Answer (score 0):

It is a `matrix` and matrix have `dimnames`.  So, either we provide the `dimnames` as a `list` when the `array` is initialized

```
arr <- array(dim = c(1,5), dimnames = list(NULL, 
           c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Name", "Surname")))
```

or assign the column names with `colnames`

```
colnames(arr) <- c("Year", "Month", "Day", "Name", "Surname")
arr
#    Year Month Day Name Surname
#[1,]   NA    NA  NA   NA      NA
```